# How do I make "make" a command?

Tags: c++, makefile

The C++ compiler I use is called `mingw32-g++.exe` but on the command line I refer to it as `g++`. But I also have make in MinGW/bin called `mingw32-make.exe` but on the command line it says `"make: command not found"` (on the git bash prompt, but on the DOS command line it works). I have to use the full name instead.

How do I make it so that I only have to use `make` instead of `mingw32-make.exe`?

Comment: command not found is because your path environment variable does not contain make.

Comment: @drescherjm My path environment variable has `MinGW/bin` which contains `mingw32-make.exe`.

Comment: @drescherjm Then where can I get the real make?

Comment: On linux there is a filesystem link. I am not sure what windows does. I do not have mingw on the current machine.

Comment: @drescherjm And why does it work when I do `mingw32-make.exe`?

Comment: Because the folder containing mingw32-make.exe is in your path environment variable as you told me above.

Comment: What does `type -p g++` say when you run it? Does it point you to `mingw32-g++.exe` or somewhere else? `g++` and friends often go through a few levels of indirection to allow for a single binary to work on various platforms, `make` does not have any such indirection generally.

Comment: @EtanReisner Actually I just discovered a `g++.exe` inside the `MinGW/bin` folder, so that must be the one it's using. There's no `make.exe` in there.

Comment: Right, my point exactly. `g++` has indirection magic that make does not. Why you don't have a `make` binary I don't know but you can do something like what @EFTH suggests in his answer if you want one and mingw will not supply one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your windows command prompt type:
doskey make=mingw32.make.exe

Now, every time you type "make" and press enter, if the program "mingw32.make.exe" is in your PATH, it will run as if you typed "mingw32.make.exe".

EDIT: If you would like to not have to keep re-creating this "alias" every time you open a new command prompt window, then you should create a .bat file (as suggested) and then create a shortcut on your desktop (or somewhere) that opens a new command prompt window using that .bat file.  Launch your command prompt using that shortcut.

How:

First, you would need to create a .bat file, name it "aliases.bat" as a file.  Then you can place this text in it: 
doskey make=mingw32.make.exe

1. After creating the file, use an Explorer window to "right-click" the aliases.bat file and click "Create shortcut" to create a new shortcut that points to "aliases.bat".
2. Now, right-click that new shortcut and edit the "Target:" property.
   a. Change the text (for example):
           C:\Users\user\Desktop\aliases.cmd
   b. To the text:
           cmd /k C:\Users\user\Desktop\aliases.cmd
   c. Click "OK" to close the properties window.
3. Now, just double-click the new shortcut file that you just created.
   a. A new command prompt window should open and you should see:

   ```
       C:\Users\user\Desktop>doskey make=mingw32.make.exe
       C:\Users\user\Desktop>
   ```
4. Type "make" and press enter.  If mingw32.make.exe is in your PATH, it will run.  Otherwise, you will see an error like this:

'mingw32.make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

1. The error means you need to add the folder name that contains mingw32.make.exe in it to the $PATH parameter in your "aliases.bat" file like so at the top of the file:
   set PATH=c:\some\folder\name;$PATH

---

If you are at a bash shell prompt, then the command for an alias is not 'doskey' instead, it is called 'alias'.  So, just type an alias at the bash prompt every time you open a new shell window, or add an alias to your .bashrc or .bash_profile file:

alias make='mingw32.make.exe'

If this does not work, find out where mingw32.make.exe is kept using 'which' command:

which mingw32.make.exe

Whatever that prints out, copy-n-paste the whole path into the alias between the single quotes, rather than just 'mingw32.make.exe'

Hope that helps.  BTW: You can create many convenient aliases (or doskeys) to save a lot of typing.

Comment: When I type that in it works on the DOS prompt (as it always was) but it doesn't work on the git bash prompt.

Comment: Ah, you at the 'bash' shell prompt, and not at a windows command prompt.  In that case, you can actually add a new alias to your .bashrc file.  To do this add a new alias for 'make' I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can use the command `g++` is because there is a file in `MinGW\bin` called `g++` (there is also the `mingw32-g++.exe` as you mentioned). There is however not a file called `make.exe`, only one called `mingw32.make.exe`. You can make a `.bat` file of your own called `make.bat` in which you run the `mingw32.make.exe` file. If you put that `.bat` file in a directory found in your path, you can use the command `make`.

Comment: Thanks. So do I just make a file called `make.bat` and inside just write `mingw32.make.exe`?

Comment: I don't know batch all too well tbh. I think you would have to do something with the arguments being passed to the bat file to send them to make. Maybe someone else knows how that works?EDIT: it seems like Darrin has the better solution

Comment: @templateboy A `.bat` file is, in simple terms, a file that contains a sequence of newline-terminated command-line commands. Simply type the commands into a file as if you are on the command-line and name the file with the extension `.bat`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your mingw32-make.exe folder,
make a copy of the file and rename it as make.exe.
It is worked for me.